# Escaping for proper shell injection prevention

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, escaping, code-injection

I need to run some shell commands from a Lua interpreter embedded into another Mac/Windows application where shell commands are the only way to achieve certain things, like opening a help page in a browser. If I have a list of arguments (which might be the result of user input), how can I escape each argument to prevent trouble?

Inspired by [this article](http://qntm.org/bash) an easy solution seems to be to escape all non-alphanumeric characters, on Unix-like systems with `\`, on Windows with `^`.  As far as I can tell, this prevents that any argument will cause

- execution of another command because of on intervening newline, `;` (Unix) or `&` (Windows)
- command substitution on Unix with `$` or `` ` ``
- variable evaluation on Windows with `%`
- redirection with `<`, `|` and `>`

In addition, any character that on the respective platform works as escape character will be escaped properly.

This seems sound to me, but are there any pitfalls I might have missed?  I know that in bash, `\` followed by a newline will effectively remove the newline, which is not a problem here.

**EDIT**

My conclusion: There is no single mechanism that by swapping the escape character will work on both Windows and *nix.  It turns out it is not so straightforward to make sure that a Windows program actually sees the command line arguments we want it to see as splitting the command string into arguments on Windows is not handled by the shell but by the called program itself.

Therefore two layers of escaping need to be taken into account:

1. First, the Windows shell will process what we give it.  What it might do is variable substitution at `%`, splitting into multiple commands at `&` or piping to another command at `|`.
2. Then, it will hand on a single command string to the called program which the program will split, ideally but not necessarily following the [rules described by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Assuming it follows these rules, one can work one's way backwards, first escaping to these rules, then escaping further for the shell.

Comment: This is why you should not be "inspired" by a random blog post written by someone who's apparently not familiar with bash. What you should do is RTFM: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting and you'll realize that quoting everything with backslash is not only overkill, it actually comes with an exception, i.e., what you're doing is wrong. What you should do instead is replace every single quote with `'\''`, then wrap the whole thing in single quotes and be done with it.

Comment: By the way, I'm specifically commenting on bash. Asking about bash and cmd in the same question is not really a good idea.

Comment: What type of system you will use windows batch or linux bash? The solutionis are completly different

Comment: @jeb Both Mac and Windows.

Comment: @ThomasW For batch even the called programs are important

Comment: @jeb Not sure whether I understand you correctly - I know and control which commands are run on the respective platforms, but the arguments will be determined at runtime. Or are you saying that some programs work with arguments that use one way of escaping (e.g. wrapping everything in quotes), but not the other (e.g. escaping everything with `^`)?

Comment: @4ae1e1 The exception you're talking about is `\\` followed by a newline, I suppose? That's incidentally a welcome effect.

Comment: @ThomasW Yes, the escaping can be different for different programs. And it gets really tricky when you call batch files with arguments. And when you have to allow passwords it's hard, as you have to allow all characters

Comment: Creating processes on Unix-like systems and Windows is quite different: while Unix-like systems use `execve` where the arguments are passed separately, Windows passes arguments in a single command line string. Although there are guidelines and built-in utilities to parse the command line on Windows, every program can make up its own command line parsing rules. Have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2007/10/03/the-windows-command-line-is-just-a-string/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx.

Comment: @Gumbo That's very useful information.

Comment: Why do you use the shell?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath As mentioned in the question, e.g. for opening help pages in a web browser or other external programs.  Possibly also some file system operations as Lua doesn't have that built in and the environment embedding Lua here doesn't support binary modules like [LuaFileSystem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/).

Comment: @ThomasW: I'm pretty sure Lua directly supports this... every programming language does.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well, Lua can read and write files, but nut stuff like listing directories, creating directories, deleting files/directories or moving them.

Comment: First google hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690913/how-to-create-a-directory-in-lua

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Which says precisely what I said: Either one uses the LuaFileSystem module, which I can't make accessible in the said environment, or one uses system calls (`os.execute()`), the latter being the reason why I asked this question. I need to prevent that something like `e:\\tmp\\test & rm *` is passed to any command on Windows or something like `/tmp/test ; rm *` on *nix. Turns out this is more involved than expected on Windows.

Comment: If you've solved this question to your satisfaction, you can enter an answer for your question below, and mark it as accepted. This will prevent it showing as unanswered.

Answer (score 4):

Calling sub-processes with dynamic arguments is prone to error and danger, and many languages don't provide good mechanisms to protect the developer. In Python, for example, [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is no longer recommended, instead the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module provides a proper mechanism for safely making system calls. In particular, you pass `subprocess.run()` a *list* of arguments, rather than a single string, thereby avoiding needing to implement any error-prone escaping in the first place.

A quick search for a `subprocess`-like tool for Lua uncovered [lua-subprocess](https://github.com/xlq/lua-subprocess), which doesn't appear to be being actively developed, but might still be better than trying to implement proper escaping yourself.

If you must do so, take a look at the Python code for [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) ([source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/63354d11a741/Lib/shlex.py#l278)) - it properly escapes an input string for use "in a shell command line":

```
# use single quotes, and put single quotes into double quotes
# the string $'b is then quoted as '$'"'"'b'
return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"
```

You ought to be able to replicate that in Lua.